# XSLT Client side Transformation not supply textarea value

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xhtml

I am doing a client-side transformation.  I want to use XSLT to take a value from XML and place it as the default text in a textarea and it is NOT working.
I have a file called AddNewBlog.aspx which is actually an XML file.  It is including a file called AddNewBlogXSL.aspx which supplies the XSL for a client side transformation.

In AddNewBlogXSL.aspx I have

```
<label for="Oohrl" id="OohrlLabel">Oohrl:</label>
<input name="ctl00$RightColumn$Oohrl" 
type="text" value="{/oohru/form/oohrl}" 
id="Oohrl" class="textEntry"/>
<br/>
<div id="validateOohrl"/>
    <label for="Description" id="DescriptionLabel">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="ctl00$RightColumn$Description" 
    rows="4" cols="50" id="Description">
        {/oohru/form/desc}
    </textarea>
```

If it helps here is the heading info for the XSL file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"><xsl:strip-space elements="*"/><!--  
Type Num
1=want
2=have
3=sell
--><xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/><xsl:template match="/">
```

My XML has this

```
<oohru>
    <form>
        <desc>asdf</desc>
        <title>a</title>
        <oohrl>jordie</oohrl>
    </form>
</oohru>
```

The heading for it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="AddNewBlogXSL.aspx"?>
```

oohrl ends up populating as the proper value but for desc I just get "{/oohru/form/desc}"

The construct only appears to be a problem for text areas

Update: It only seems to be a problem with asp.net text area controls...

```
    <asp:TextBox id="Description" TextMode="MultiLine" 
Columns="50" Rows="4" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static"><xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />
    </asp:TextBox>
```

puts the literal value

```
<xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" />
```

into the box on the page

whereas

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="5"><xsl:value-of select="/oohru/form/desc" /></textarea>
```

Puts the actual proper value into the text area....

Comment: It's not your code that's wrong, it's the way you are running it (or not running it). Which you haven't told us anything about.

Comment: Hopefully that helps clarify the way I am running it.  Clientside transformation with that file being included as the XSL sheet

Answer (score 0):

The most common situations that I can think of that would cause that are

1. You haven't actually run it through an XSLT processor. I'm going to
   assume that you have!
2. You have misdeclared the XSLT namespace. Make
   sure that you have something like this at the top of your
   stylesheet:

   `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Remember that prefix is just a representation of the namespace itself. That namespace name has to be *exactly* as I've supplied it above.

Comment: It says for #2 make sure you have something like this at the top of your stylesheet and I just see "..." I think it has to be in a code block whatever you were going to say

Comment: Here is the top of my style sheet
`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"><xsl:strip-space elements="*"/><!--  
Type Num
1=want
2=have
3=sell
--><xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/><xsl:template match="/">`

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure why my example wasn't displaying. Forced it. Your stylesheet is suffering from error 2 - you need to declare the xsl namespace.